# An identity related to Legendre polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, analysis, hypergeometric-function

Let $m$ be a positive integer. I believe the the following identity
 $$1+\sum_{k=1}^m (-1)^k\frac{P(k,m)}{(2k)!}=(-1)^m\frac{2^{2m}(m!)^2}{(2m)!}$$
 where $P(k,m)=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (2m-2i)(2m+2i+1)$, is true, but I don't see a quick proof. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $P(k,m) = (-1)^k 4^k \cdot (-m)_k \cdot \left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)_k$, where $(a)_k$ stands for the Pochhammer's symbol. Thus the sums of the left-hand-side of your equality is
$$
 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{P(k,m)}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^k \frac{(-m)_k \left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)_k}{ (2k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-m)_k \left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)_k}{ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k k!} = {}_2F_1\left( -m, m + \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}; 1 \right) = 
$$
Per identity [07.23.03.0003.01](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0003.01) ${}_2F_1(-m,b;c;1) = \frac{(c-b)_m}{(c)_m}$:
$$
  {}_2F_1\left( -m, m + \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}; 1 \right) = \frac{(-m)_m}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m} = \frac{(-1)^m m!}{ \frac{(2m)!}{m! 2^{2m}} } = (-1)^m \frac{4^m}{\binom{2m}{m}}
$$
The quoted identity follows as a solution of the contiguity relation for $f_m(z) = {}_2F_1(-m,b;c;z)$:
$$
    (m+1)(z-1) f_m(z) + (2+c+2m-z(b+m+1)) f_{m+1}(z) - (m+c+1) f_{m+2}(z) = 0
$$
Setting $z=1$ and assuming that $f_m(1)$ is finite the recurrence relation drops the order, and can be solved in terms of Pochhammer's symbols.

Comment: Are there books where I can look up about $f_m(z)$ and the contiguity relation you mentioned?

Comment: Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Gauss.27_contiguous_relations) of Gauss's ${}_2F_1(z)$ is a good start. Any book on special functions is bound to discuss them.

Comment: The identity ${}_2F_1(-m,b;c;1) = \frac{(c-b)_m}{(c)_m}$ also follows from Gauss Summation formula: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_nn!}=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}$.

Comment: @TCL Yes, but then it requires $\Re(c-a-b)>0$ which does not hold for $a=-m$, $b=m+1/2$ and $c=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks. But perhaps one can still use that (with a smaller a or b) and then take limit?

Comment: Yeah, I think that works, just make $b$ smaller, use the formula, then let b approach $m+1/2$. This works b/c the infinite sum in this case is a finite sum.